# Speech Recognizer and Text to speech(Google Api) Swift - Voice Problem

Tags: swift, speech-to-text

I am using both speech to text and text to speech(Google api) in the same Viewcontrols. When the page is opened, when the word listen button is pressed, a very loud sound is output from the iPhone. It works fine when the speech to text button is pressed. The problem is I press the text to speech button after the speech to text is finished, then the audio output is very low. Text to speech volume drops a lot. No matter what I did. I stop the necessary things with Speech to text, but it still doesn't work. Would you help me with this topic?

```
import Foundation
import Speech

class SpeakingManager: NSObject, SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate {
    
    static let shared = SpeakingManager()
    
    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    let speechRecognizer: SFSpeechRecognizer? = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
    let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
    var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?
    var resultString = ""
    
    //MARK: - Recognize Speech
    func recordAndRecognizeSpeech() {
        
        let node = audioEngine.inputNode
        let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
        node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
            self.request.append(buffer)
        }
        audioEngine.prepare()
        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
            print("There has been an audio engine error.")
        }
        
        resultString = ""
        recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { result, error in
            if let result = result {
                let bestString = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                self.resultString = bestString
                
            } else if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
    
    func cancelRecording() {
        recognitionTask?.finish()
        recognitionTask = nil
        
        // stop audio
        request.endAudio()
        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
    }
}
```